# ESXi 6.5.0 create user to log in web UI and start a VM

Tags: vmware-esxi, user-permissions

I need to create an user for vmware that:

1. Can access to ESXi Web ui
2. View all the VM with their state
3. Can start a stopped virtual machine (the vm could change).

**What I'm looking for ?**

I want to assign minimal permission and i don't know what are; also the user cannot log in the UI or the shell (at least i'll create a bash script)

**What I have done:**

1. Create an user -> done via the Web UI (Host > Manage > Security & Users)
2. Create a custom role "XRole" (same menu section)
3. Add user+role to the host (Host > Actions button > Permissions )

But this user cannot log in. I have added all the permission to "XRole" but no changes.

**Why?**

Sometimes the Windows Server guest shutdown and it not restarts. There is no IT experts in the customer's office so they better cannot access via root user.

Comment: So you have non-technical users who just need to restart a single guest VM periodically? If so why not just use a powercli script?

Comment: @Chopper3 the vm may vary ( I updated the question, thanks). The offices' terminals are linux based and i cannot install anything. I don't know powercli, but i suppose I need an user to log in too, so the user problem will be the same

Comment: With PowerCLI the valid ESXi user is required. A question: do you use ESXi server without vCenter?

Comment: @batistuta09 yes, i've no vCenter